# How to post json object in web service

Tags: c#, json, service, itunes

Can any one help me please that how to post Json object to web service using c#? Actually I am trying to verify an App Store Transaction Receipt in C#.

follow this link to have an enough idea.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1

Please help me if you have some idea or knowledge.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string receiptData = "(receipt bytes here)";

string url = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";

HttpWebRequest oneWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
oneWebRequest.Method = "POST";
oneWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

string json = "{ \"receipt-data\": \"" + receiptData + "\" }";

oneWebRequest.ContentLength = json.Length;
using (System.IO.StreamWriter oneStreamWriter =
  new System.IO.StreamWriter(oneWebRequest.GetRequestStream(),
                             System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
{
    oneStreamWriter.Write(json);
}

HttpWebResponse oneWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)oneWebRequest.GetResponse();

// ReceiptStatus is a class with two public string properties (status & receipt)
DataContractJsonSerializer oneDataContractJsonSerializer =
  new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Product>));
ReceiptStatus oneReceiptStatus =
   (ReceiptStatus) oneDataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(
      oneWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
   );
```

Comment: See Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433551/problems-sending-and-receiving-json-between-asp-net-web-service-and-asp-net-web

Comment: You will likely need to add a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization for DataContractJsonSerializer.

Comment: @Dmitry - I have no idea and the link in the original question that my answer was likely based off of seems dead.  Sorry.

Comment: @Dmitry - I can get to the original question link now.  I believe "List<Product>" should be "ReceiptStatus", that was just a cut and paste error.

Answer (score 0):

try with json.Net http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx