# Limit the location in a city

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to do register the users limit to location.
How I can after get location of user let to do register just in a city ?
Thank for every ideas .
I use a web api Project , when I get the data from android like this: 
{
 "UserName" : "Hosein.dafeyan" 
,"Password" : "1234" 
, "Latitude": "32.629134" 
,"Longitude":"51.646930" 
}
 And after then get in web api like a ViewModel, I check this location is in purpose city or no. After All then do return to android is valid or no.

For example I want limit like this picture:
[image: Limit location]

Comment: can  you please share your code

Comment: You need to at least tell us how you are getting the location...

Comment: Please give a lot more detail. Do users type the location in a textbox, or do they select it from a Dropdown, or do you use Browser Location access? Show the code for your actual scenario.

Comment: I use a web api Project , when I get the data from android
like this:
{
"UserName" : "Hosein.dafeyan"
,"Password" : "1234"
, "Latitude": "32.629134"
,"Longitude":"51.646930"
}
And after then get in web api like a ViewModel, I check this location is in purpose city or no.
After All then do return to android is valid or no.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Geocoding API by Google. The [official document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse) includes example requests and responses.

> The Geocoding API is a service that provides geocoding and reverse geocoding of addresses.
>
> Reverse geocoding is the process of converting geographic coordinates into a human-readable address.

You can make an HTTP GET request as follows:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=32.629134,51.646930&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

If you don't know how to do this with C#, you can use these references in SO:

[json call with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982765/json-call-with-c-sharp)

[How do I make calls to a REST api using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620278/how-do-i-make-calls-to-a-rest-api-using-c)

Answer (score 1):

So when you want limited users per location. Then you have to this in steps

1. Get Location info of user
2. Get the already registered users count for that and if it's already reached the limit and if not let user get register.

So for

**1. Get Location info of user**

you can use [this](https://www.geoplugin.com/), Here is the [Example](http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp)

You can make ajax request to [this](https://www.geoplugin.com/) and get back this info to your server to get user location

**Note:** though this approach has limitations that if user is using VPN or proxy site it will give you false data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GPS coordinates, check against a polygon that describes your acceptable area.